# How to check for duplicate records in .csv using java

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file:

```
10;name1;id1
20;name2;id2
10;name3;id3
```

Row for Row i push the data to a method called forward:

> forward(nr, name, id);

How can i check the whole csv if "nr" is a duplicate? like in the above example is: 10.

My code now:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = scanner.next();
        if (index == 0)
            nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
        else if (index == 1)
            name = data;
        else if (index == 2)
            id = data;
        else
            System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    forward(nr, name, id);  
}
```

If a duplicate is found, i just want to print it on the screen.

Comment: Is "nr" the only field that you want to check for duplicates ?

Comment: Yes i only want to check "nr" for duplicates, thanks :)

Comment: What is the required behavior if a dupe is detected? Ignore dupe or replace original?

Comment: Just print a text on the screen. Good question, i will add it above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map<Long, String>`. Each time before you forward the output you can check if the Map contains the key (the number) already.

```
Map<Long, String> entryMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();
[...]
if (!entryMap.containsKey(nr)) {
     entryMap.put(nr, name);
     forward(nr, name, id);
} else 
     System.out.println("Entry with number " + nr + " already added to .csv file");
```

If only the number is relevant and you don't need to put any exceptions (e.g., `entry with name and number is already in the file`), you might want to choose other data structures, e.g., a `List`.

As I read in the comments above, if replacing is your intention you could the following:

Create a class that keeps the parameters:

```
public class CsvEntry {
       private int number;
       private String name, id;

       public CsvEntry(number, name, id) {
           this.number = number;
           this.name = name;
           this.id = id;
       }
       // getters & setters
}
```

And then change the `Map` to:

```
Map<Long, CsvEntry> entryMap = new TreeMap<Long, CsvEntry>();
// TreeMap so the entries are sorted.
[...]
entryMap.put(nr, new CsvEntry(nr, name, id));
// after populating the map, e.g., after the outer loop
forward(entryMap);
```

And then in forward you simply loop the map for the output.

Comment: could you explain to me what the code will be in your example at [...]

Comment: @MeesvanZ Yes, the [...] simply stands for your code inbetween. So, you initalize the `Map` before you start the first loop (otherwise it will be overwritten). The next part `if (!entryMap.containsKey(nr))` is located before you forward your entry (you move the `forward` call into the `if`).

Answer (score 2):

You could use **java.util.Set** to check duplication.

Sample code:

```
java.util.Set<Integer> nrSet = new java.util.HashSet<Integer>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = scanner.next();
        if (index == 0)
            nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
        else if (index == 1)
            name = data;
        else if (index == 2)
            id = data;
        else
            System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    if (nrSet.contains(nr)) { // check duplication
        System.out.println("Duplicate nr:" + nr);
    } else {
        forward(nr, name, id);  
        nrSet.add(nr);// add as forwarded 
    }
}
```

**java.util.Set nrSet = new java.util.HashSet();**
holds already forwarded **nr** set.

**if (nrSet.contains(nr))** checks duplication
 
**nrSet.add(nr);** add just forwarded **nr**

Comment: I think it is still not clear for me, what do you do before if (nrSet.contains(nr))?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick solution that require only small modifications on current code then you can declare an `ArrayList<Integer> nrs` before this code and inside the test `if (index == 0)` you check `if (nrs.contains(nr))` then you can display your message and `break;`, `else nrs.add(nr);`

Your code will be like this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> nrs = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    scanner = new Scanner(line);
    scanner.useDelimiter(";");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String data = scanner.next();
        if (index == 0){
            nr = Integer.parseInt(data);
            if(nrs.contains(nr)) {
                System.err.println("Duplicate record : "+nr);
                break;
            } else nrs.add(nr);
        }
        else if (index == 1)
            name = data;
        else if (index == 2)
            id = data;
        else
            System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    forward(nr, name, id);  
}
```